# Java - MimetypesFileTypeMap always returning application/octet

Tags: java, file, mime-types

i am trying to get the mime type from a file but it always seems to be returning

```
 application/octet

 MimetypesFileTypeMap mftm = new MimetypesFileTypeMap();
 System.out.println("Mime Type of " + file.getName() + " is " +
                     mftm.getContentType(file));
```

I know for a fact that the file in question is a png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better try:

```
FileTypeMap.getDefaultFileTypeMap();
```

Comment: return "application/octet", but the web browser display Okay

Answer (score 2):

FYI - if this is Java 7, there's a known bug in the early Java 7 JREs that has been fixed: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7096063